# I respect the ways that the tribes eat in?

Tags: grammar, usage

I have never seen or heard this sentence, "I respect the ways that the tribes eat in."

I think the sentence should be

> "I respect the ways that the tribes eat."

or

> "I respect the ways in which the tribes eat."

or

> "I respect the ways the tribes eat."

What do you think?

Comment: If you have never seen or heard that sentence, and you have some good alternate ways to express this thought,  why do you ask the question?

Comment: Since you are asking about it, you must have seen it somewhere! Can you supply any more context?

Answer (score -1):

The phrase "I respect the ways that the tribes eat in." actually means that you respect all the ways the tribes eat.

In the end, all of your the sentences are right.

The thing that might cause you difficulty in the understanding of this sentence is the phrasal verb **eat in**

> **Eat in** : to have a meal at home rather than in a restaurant
>
> [Cambridge dictionary for **eat in**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/eat-in)